# How do I change the font and font size in a drupal7 article?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have this article:

> First shalt thou take out the Holy Pin, then shalt thou count to three, no more, no less. Three shall be the number thou shalt count, and the number of the counting shall be three. Four shalt thou not count, neither count thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three. Five is right out. Once the number three, being the third number, be reached, then lobbest thou thy Holy Hand Grenade of Antioch towards thy foe, who being naughty in My sight, shall snuff it."

All I want to do is controlling the font attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the several inspectors available (Firebug,Dragonfly etc) and inspect the article.

The output and especially the one to the right is what you are looking for. The font-size attribute will be shown together with the stylesheet and the line number. Adjust to whatever font-size you want.